# Tournament of 9 people in teams of 3, everyone teaming up and competing evenly?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a tournament of 9 people in changing teams of three, held at one field, one team pausing each game.

f.e.: Game One: ABC vs DEF Pausing: GHI

Game two: AEI vs DBG Pausing: CFH

Is it possible to mix and team the 9 players so that they each play with everyone the same times and against everyone the same times? What is the minimum number of games needed to satisfy both conditions and how can one find a matchplan?

Comment: Assume we start with $A$ playing four games, with each other player on his team once.  He has played against $12$ players, so against each other on average $\frac 32$ times.  We then have hope if we do two rounds of this, so each player plays $8$ games, two with each other person and three against each other.  The total number of games is then $\frac {9\cdot 8}6=12$ as each player has played eight times and each games has six players.  Each player then sits out four games.  I would now start constructing and see what trouble hits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  There are $$\frac{1}{2}{9\choose 3}{6 \choose 3}=840$$ ways to choose two teams that play each other.  If you play 840 games, once in each of these ways, then both conditions will be satisfied.

A more interesting question is what is the minimum number of games required to meet both conditions.

Comment: True, that is more interesting! I edited my question... :-)